When sending a request to the local django server, it returns a 404 error, although the correct parameters and the correct url are passed
I need to make a view class so that I can export a file in xlsx or csv format, depending on what is passed in the parameters, and I got this code:
class ExportXLSXandCSV(APIView):
def get(self, request, model_name, format):
models = {
'Country': Country,
'Car': Car,
'Manufacturer': Manufacturer,
'Comments': Comments
}
    if model_name not in models:
        return Response({"detail": "Invalid model."}, status=400)

    model = models[model_name]
    data = model.objects.all()
    serializer = serializers.serialize('python', data)

    if format == 'xlsx':
        df = pd.DataFrame(serializer)
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={model_name.lower()}_export.xlsx'
        df.to_excel(response, engine='openpyxl', index=False)
        return response
    elif format == 'csv':
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment; filename={model_name.lower()}_export.csv'
        serializer.serialize_csv(response, data)
        return response

Также вот код моей url:
path('api/export/str:model_name/str:format/', ExportXLSXandCSV.as_view(), name='export_data')
И вот какую ошибку я получаю в терминале при отправке запроса     http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/export/?model_name=Car&format=xlsx
ошибка в терминале: "GET /api/export/http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/export/?model_name=Car&format=xlsx HTTP/1.1" 404 6238
Я пробовал менять параметры, а также пробовал отправлять их по-другому (в postman), я только начинаю и пока не могу знать куда дальше следует смотреть для того, чтобы решить эту проблему, прошу помочь мне

it seems you not set "format" value.

And where should I install it, since the format is present in the view and query @django.seolpyo.com

you use "format" variable in if code...

Sorry for the late response, I forgot that I asked the question, and yes I solved the problem!
